# How do you do an if else statement in JSX/ES6 shorthand?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsx

My data looks like this

```
{
 foo1: { name: 'Sara', rep: 'John' },
 foo2: { name: 'Bob'},
 foo3: { name: 'Mike', rep: 'Ray'}
}
```

My goal is do display both rep and name if there is rep and just display name

JSX return

```
 if (rep) {
   <b> {rep}(rep)</b>
     <p>{name}<p/>
   } else {
   <b>{name}</b>
  }
```

Assuming something like this

```
 {rep ? <b>{rep}(rep)</b><p>{name}</p> : <b>{name}</b> }
```

Comment: Did you  try that? What happened?

Comment: Other than that `<p/>` should be `</p>`, that's how you usually see it done.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is pretty good.

You could do something like this:

```
{rep ?
    (
        <div>
            <b>{ rep } (rep)</b>
            <p>{ name }</p>
        </div>

    )    
: (
    <b>{ name }</b>
)}
```

You can only return one HTML Element so you need to wrap the `b` and `p` tag into a `div`.

As @a_programmer pointed out in the comments: "With react 16/fiber you can also use `<React.fragment>` instead of `<div>` to keep the dom clean"

Comment: With react 16/fiber you can also use `<React.fragment>` instead of `<div>` to keep the dom clean

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will always have the name you could do something like:

```
return(
  <span>
    {rep && <b>{rep}</b>}
    <p>{name}</p>
  </span>
)
```

Or if you don't:

```
return(
  <span>
    {rep && <b>{rep}</b>}
    {name && <p>{name}</p>}
  </span>
)
```